# Replicate the Interesting tab in the Stack Exchange API

Tags: feature-request, api, interesting-page

Stack Overflow has an "Interesting" tab. I would like to query the Stack Exchange API to get "Interesting" questions back just like in the website but the API has no way to do this.

So I actually only see one possible solution after I have gathered the user tags:
perform multiple queries for each tag and then calculate the scores myself.

I would really like to avoid this as it could make pagination a real horror.